# How to stop Reading NFC , if my condition is not respected?

Tags: java, android, xml, nfc

I want to stop the NFC reading process and display a textView in case of the my if condition is not respected.
If I do not have the 'S', I want the process of reading to be stopped
my current code doesn't stop the process.

```
 private void readFromIntent(Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
                || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
                || NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
            Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
            NdefMessage[] msgs = null;
            if (rawMsgs != null) {
                msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
                    msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
                }
            }
            buildTagViews(msgs);
        }
    }
    private void buildTagViews(NdefMessage[] msgs) {
        if (msgs == null || msgs.length == 0) return;

        String text = "";
//        String tagId = new String(msgs[0].getRecords()[0].getType());
        byte[] payload = msgs[0].getRecords()[0].getPayload();
        String textEncoding = ((payload[0] & 128) == 0) ? "UTF-8" : "UTF-16"; // Get the Text Encoding
        int languageCodeLength = payload[0] & 0063; // Get the Language Code, e.g. "en"
        // String languageCode = new String(payload, 1, languageCodeLength, "US-ASCII");

        try {
            // Get the Text

            text = new String(payload, languageCodeLength + 1, payload.length - languageCodeLength - 1, textEncoding);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.e("UnsupportedEncoding", e.toString());
        }


        if (text.charAt(0)!='S'){
            Alerte.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
else{
            Alerte.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "stop the NFC reading process"? As it is impossible to stop the system process from reading NFC Tags (Other than opening the NFC settings page to get the user to turn NFC off). Or do you mean stop your App from receiving NFC data and allowing the system to handle them (which usually means popup window will be show). Or make it look like that they are not being read? even though they are (this can be done using the better `enableReaderMode` API but not with the old Intent based API because the system always beeps on read)

Comment: I mean stop my App from receiving NFC data and allowing the system to handle them with as you said a message shown in a pop up window

Answer (score 0):

Your probably using the Foreground dispatch mechanism to receive the NFC data to your running app though you don't show this code.

So to stop receiving NFC Intent messages just call `disableForegroundDispatch` on the nfcAdaptor https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter#disableForegroundDispatch(android.app.Activity)